# How to assign unique observations to values within a group?

Tags: r

How do you number values by group in R?
for example i want the following table:

```
100 1
100 2
100 3
200 1
200 2
200 3
300 1
300 2
300 3
```

I want to write a function that will create a unique value for each member of particular group. Group here being '100', '200', '300'. I want to generate unique value for each member of the group and then when the group changes, I want R to start numbering each of the values in that group from 1 again. How do I accomplish this? Is it possible to do this with base R?

Answer (score 1):

#### base R:

```
# Example data frame: 
df <- data.frame(group = c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300))

df$number <- ave(df$group, df$group, FUN = seq_along)
```

#### dplyr:

```
library(dplyr) # > 1.1.0
df %>% 
  mutate(number = row_number(), .by=group)
```

```
 group number
1   100      1
2   100      2
3   100      3
4   200      1
5   200      2
6   200      3
7   300      1
8   300      2
9   300      3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, in the first answer, how do i group them if the values are higher in number? the groups are much larger than three 100-s or three 200-s. I cannot manually type them out. Please help

Comment: First: if you have 100, 100, 100 you can do rep(100, 3). Then the data in the first answer is already grouped by `group`.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-base R solution you can use `data.table::rowid()` or `row_id()` from my package `timeplyr`.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(timeplyr)
df <- tibble(group = c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300))

# data.table 
rowid(df$group)
#> [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
# timeplyr
row_id(df, group)
#> [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
# Descending order
row_id(df, group, ascending = FALSE)
#> [1] 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>